# Wildfly Service won't start

Tags: linux, service, jboss, wildfly, centos7

I'm trying to install WildFly 17.0.0 on CentOS7.
I'm following this page instructions: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-centos-7/ But, when I get to the point where I should see the service running, it sends the following message:

```
[root@ opt]# systemctl status wildfly
● wildfly.service - The WildFly Application Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 14 11:08:49  systemd[1]: Started The WildFly Application Server.
```

My Java is installed also:

```
[root@ opt]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

And I followed all the step several times and is still not working.

I found some blogs saying there is a "descrption" field on the bat file, where you should remove the quotes. But when I go into the file, the quotes comes already removed and there is comments on the file saying the quotes were already removed.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Regards

Answer (score 9):

I Found the problem. 
There is a file called wildfly.conf where you must add some configuration the page I was following didn't mention. So you must add the following lines for the wildfly to run:

```
    ## Location of JDK 
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66"

    ## Location of WildFly 
    JBOSS_HOME="/opt/wildfly"

    ## The username who should own the process. 
    JBOSS_USER=wildfly
```

Now it is running.

Comment: Thank you it helped me!

Comment: Big help. Thank you so much.